# what am I supposed to do when I experience this exception (com.google.firebase.FirebaseException) while creating user accounts using email/password?

Tags: java, android, firebase-authentication

I am trying to create user accounts using Firebase Authentication via auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(custEmail, custPasswd) but I keep getting this exception (com.google.firebase.FirebaseException: An internal error has occurred. [ 7: ])

I have enable authentication using email/password. I have also updated my project's SHA1 certificate in the Firebase console and re-downloaded the google-services.json file.

```
 private FirebaseAuth auth;

try {
            FirebaseApp.initializeApp(this);
            //Get Firebase auth instance
            auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.e(TAG, "FirebaseApp or FirebaseAuth could be throwing this error-->" + e.getMessage());
        } 

//REGISTERING THE USER TO FIREBASE DB
    public void registerUser() {

        progressDialog.setMessage("Registering user...");
        progressDialog.show();

        //create user
        auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(custEmail, custPasswd).addOnSuccessListener(this, new OnSuccessListener<AuthResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(AuthResult authResult) {

                //save user at "USERS"
                mUsers.child(custName).setValue(user, new DatabaseReference.CompletionListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@Nullable DatabaseError databaseError, @NonNull DatabaseReference databaseReference) {
                        if (databaseError == null) {

                            //sendLinkToEmail(custEmail);
                            progressDialog.dismiss();

                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Your registration was successful", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            Log.e(TAG, "Data is saved successfully to --> " + databaseReference.toString());

                            getSharedPreferences("PREFERENCE", MODE_PRIVATE).edit()
                                    .putBoolean("isFirstRun", false).apply();

                            //login to main activity
                            Intent intent = new Intent(OTPActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                            startActivity(intent);
                            finish();

                        } else {

                            progressDialog.dismiss();
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        }).addOnFailureListener(this, new OnFailureListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {

                e.printStackTrace();
                Log.e(TAG, e.toString());

                progressDialog.dismiss();

            }
        });
    }
```

I expect the new user to be registered using his email and password and stored in my database but instead am getting this exception ( com.google.firebase.FirebaseException: An internal error has occurred. [ 7: ])

Comment: Possibly same as [firebase issue #474](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-unity/issues/474): `AuthError.Failure: Firebase.FirebaseException: An internal error has occurred. [ 7: ]`

Comment: Doug Stevenson....It's that very issue but no solution to it in that thread.